# PHP возвращает false при сравнении, но переменные одинаковые

Tags: php, html, url

Не буду подробно расписывать что за код и откуда, но в общем есть две переменные, одна - из БД, вторая - из адресной строки(закодирована)
код:

```
if (rawurldecode($_GET['formula']) === $row['formula']) {
    echo 'success!';
}
else{
    echo rawurldecode($_GET['formula']).'<br>'.$row['formula'].'<br>';
}
```

Всегда выводит второй вариант, даже в том случае когда переменные полностью идентичны, пример вывода:

3.3.1 TOP N+/BE - 20/AR/CHROMATECH ULTRA/PS

3.3.1 TOP N+/BE - 20/AR/CHROMATECH ULTRA/PS

В чем может быть проблема?Она присутствует только когда в стоке есть *+*, в других вариантах работает

//все таки с плюсом перестало работать, так как до этого использовал просто urldecode() - оно работало, но есть + в некоторых строках поэтому вариант не подошел

Comment: `===` сравнение включая типы данных, используйте `==` или приводите типы данных в ручную

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков об этом тоже думал, пробовал - та же проблема, говорю же - во всех строках без плюса работает, типы данных ни при чем

Comment: http://www.php.su/rawurldecode прочтите примечание, а в браузере смотрется будет одинакого =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков но мне и не нужен пробел вместо плюса) и как это оно же выводит две переменные, как они могут быть не одинаковы? И что вместо этого можно использовать? так как кодирую на js а декодирую на php

Comment: так я вам намекнул на попытку использовать urldecode и в php просто заменить + на пробел =) по поводу разного вида, всякие &gt; выглядят как положено своими символами =)

Comment: плюс нельзя заменять, из бд он поступает всегда в одном виде, да и если его убрать то результат может быть совсем другой)

Comment: Сделайте проверки ради посимвольное сравнение обоих строк, и посмотрите результат, тогда можно будет предположить что либо, ибо нам отсюда не видно настоящих входных данных, видно только "внешнее\визуальное" сходство и уже после обработки и не более того